# Recursive python function in a for loop

Tags: python

Would like to dig deeper with recursion as a prelude to implementing minimax for tictactoe project for school

First time poster.Been trying to implement minimax on tictactoe. Saw a bunch of code but my project requires looking at the path to terminal state individually to simplify space complexity. I wish to learn more about recursion so I created a small code for proof of concept. I am able to get the utility function of win/loss/draw (1, -1, 0) if matrix is complete BUT if matrix has let's say 3 missing spots , my understanding is that the AI agent has to game play out the various scenarios, fill out the missing spots and do iterations of alternating human/AI moves and stop when a terminal state is achieved. My code below keeps going instead of stopping. The ideal progression should stop when a win is recorded which is the 3rd matrix of XXX. but it kept going trying to fill the last blank space.

```
import numpy as np

filename="xFlux.txt"
m=np.loadtxt(filename,delimiter=" ",dtype=str)



def checkWin(m, mark):
    won = False # Variable holding the return value

    # Check wins by examining each combination of positions
    # Check each row
    for i in range(3):
        won = True
        for j in range(3):

            if m[i][j]!=mark:
                won=False
                break        

        if won:
            break

    # Check each column
    if not won:
        for i in range(3):
            won = True
            for j in range(3):
                if m[j][i]!=mark:
                    won=False
                    break
            if won:
                break

    # Check first diagonal
    if not won:
        for i in range(3):
            won = True
            if m[i][i]!=mark:
                won=False
                break

    # Check second diagonal
    if not won:
        for i in range(3):
            won = True
            if m[2-i][i]!=mark:
                won=False
                break

    return won

# Determines whether the board is full
# If full, returns True, and False otherwise
def noMoreMoves(m):
   return (m !=' ').all()

def minimax(m):
  print('entering Minimax')
  print (m)
  print('-----')

  if checkWin(m,'O'):
        # Computer won
        return 1


  elif checkWin(m,'X'):
        print('entering win X',m)
        return -1


  elif  noMoreMoves(m):
        # No moves left -> draw
        return 0 

#find empty cells
print('entering nexted for')
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
         if m[i][j] ==' ':
              print('$$$',i,j)
              m[i][j]='X'
              poke.append((i,j))
              print(m)
              print( poke)
              minimax(m)

#poke is set that will storing the (x,y) tuple
#for the simulated marks which need to be erased later


poke=[]                        
#print (m)
evalX = minimax(m)
print ('eval returns ' , evalX)
```

Comment: I think there's a problem with your listing.  At the top you load 'm', that's fine.  Then there are a some function definitions.  Then you execute the nested for loops, but should the 'if' code be executed, `poke` would be an undefined variable.

Comment: If you just want a refresher on recursive functions generally, google is your friend. If it's a question how minimax works, please clarify what the question is. Otherwise, can you please boil this all down to an absolutely minimal example of what language feature has you stumped?

Comment: Thanks to Paul and Ian. I dug deeper into recursion and discovered that my functions did not have a base case which prevented the functions from unwinding.I am good.. for now. Thanks.